# Android: Passing String parameters in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, rss, android-asynctask

I'm implementing an Android app to load RSS feed. It works perfectly fine until I decided to add a new screen for displaying two buttons and trying to pass a String value to the AsyncTask. The idea is this: The screen will display two buttons for the users to choose. Once the user has clicked on one of the buttons, it will invoke the AsyncTask along with  the string value(url) to readRSS(url), then the rss feed is displayed by displayRSS(url). The readRSS(url) will load the RSS feed accordingly.

My codes are as below:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RSSProActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rss);
        startLoadRSS();

    }

    private void startLoadRSS(){
        new RSS_Load().execute();
    }

    //
    private void preReadRSS()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reading RSS, Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

        private StringBuffer readRSS(String url)
        {
            //depends on the inputs, will set the String value accordingly. It should be "url" but using the default value at the moment.

            String urlStr = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDZ00059.warnings_vic.xml";
            AndroidSAXFeedParser saxFeedParser = new AndroidSAXFeedParser(urlStr);
            List<RSSItem> parse = saxFeedParser.parse();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(parse.size()+" items found");
            for(RSSItem item:parse){
                sb.append(item.getTitle()+"posted at "+item.getDate());
                sb.append(item.getDescription());
            }
            return sb;
        }

        private void displayRSS()
        {
            StringBuffer sb = readRSS(url);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(sb.toString());
            setContentView(textView);
            Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        //AsyncTask
        public class RSS_Load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              preReadRSS();
           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             readRSS();
                       // should be readRSS(url) here
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
              //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
          //    updateProgressBar(values[0]);

           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              super.onPostExecute(result);
           //   dismissProgressBar();
                // should be displayRSS(url) here
            displayRSS();

           }               

 }
}
```

I'm trying to change the value in RSS_Load extends AsyncTask but it gives me compile error. So I changed the protected Void doInBackground(String... url) then passing the url to readRSS(url) but it doesn't work either. How should I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work either"?

Comment: @K-ballo means it still gives me compilation error. But I managed to fixed it using the answer provided by CaseyB by passing arg0[0] to readRSS().

Comment: If my answer worked for you then you chose click the check mark next to it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ... means that it's actually passing an array of that type.  So if you change it to:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0)
```

You would need to do this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0)
{
    readRSS(arg0[0]);
    // should be readRSS(url) here
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! One more question, how should I invoke the AsyncTask? Initially I was doing this:
startLoadRSS();

private void startLoadRSS(){
     new RSS_Load().execute();
    }

Does it mean I can just invoke it by startLoadRSS(url)?

Comment: @princess_blackforest: `private void startLoadRSS(String url) { new RSS_Load().execute(url); }`. Just a tip: create an explicit constructor for your `AsyncTask` that takes all parameters you need for execution. That way it becomes way more difficult to accidentally pass in the wrong variable, or none at all. It also avoids having to look at the actual implementation of `doInBackground(...)` in order to understand what data it needs.

Comment: Please... change your `arg0` to something meaningful... coding with default argument names, or worse, bad ones, makes programming difficult to do and worse, can muddle your debugging process after a few goes.

Comment: @Phix Agreed, I just left it that way so as to change as little as possible from the OP

Comment: Yea sorry, wasnt directed directly at you :-)